# How to find the particular text stored in the file data txt and it occurs only once?

Tags: linux

I want to know why we use `uniq -u` with `sort` command?

If I use only `uniq -u data.txt` then it print each line, not the unique line that I required as result.

Comment: Try using grep instead.

Comment: Improve formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I got with:

```
$ uniq --help
```

> Usage: uniq [OPTION]... [INPUT [OUTPUT]]
>
> Filter *adjacent matching lines* from INPUT (or standard input), writing to OUTPUT (or standard output).
>
> [...]

Therefore you want to use `sort` before sending your content to `uniq`, in order to have all matching lines adjacent.

Answer (score 0):

`uniq` filters out adjacent, matching lines.

Example `file.txt`

```
Hello World
It is sunshine
Warm weather
Hello World
Hello World
Winter is coming
It is sunshine
Hello World
Java code
Java code

$ uniq -u file.txt
Hello World
It is sunshine
Warm weather
Winter is coming
It is sunshine
Hello World
```

All adjacent matching lines have been removed. For example, the two lines containing `Hello World`

Sorting will group matching lines together.

```
$ sort file.txt
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
It is sunshine
It is sunshine
Java code
Java code
Warm weather
Winter is coming
```

Piping the output of sort will achieve removal of duplicate lines.

```
$ sort file.txt | uniq -u
Warm weather
Winter is coming
```